# Position horizontally and vertically too small carousel images in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display in carousel the images that maximum size is `220x220px`, but they can be smaller in one or both dimensions. The should be centered both vertically and horizontally, but not streched.

The carousel is of fixed size `220x220px`, so it should be easy to position images like this:

```
left: 50%; /*move picture to the middle */
margin-left: -110px; /* go back to the center */
top: 50%;
margin-top: -110px;
```

but it does not work. The pictures are still sticked to left top corner of the carousel.

I made a bootply to ilustrate this:
http://www.bootply.com/freyja/JnJ1kc3d3G#

I also tried other techniques, like using `table-cell` technique and `vertical-align`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) to center an element horizontally and vertically:

```
position: relative; /* or absolute */
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TU52/2/)

Comment: `position: relative` will also work. I mean no need of absolute. unnecessary in this case :)

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer! This worked very well. I updated my bootply http://www.bootply.com/freyja/JnJ1kc3d3G# with your answer, in case somebody wants to see it included in carousel.